# A Publisher with RSS as Datasource

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am writing some code to fetch news from rss feed and publish n items at once every m hours to another site.

I compare the update xml file with the previous one saved on server using PHP. 
I load the two xml into php array and the latest post is filter out using array_diff_assoc().

If the number of the latest post>n, the older one will be publish first, the rest will be done next time. Therefore I need some ways to store which item have publish or not.

What is the simplest way to do so? I don't want to apply mySQL/S for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just store those not published?  Then each time, pull up the old, stored ones, and append to the list those new ones ID'd by array_diff_assoc().  Publish n, and if number > n, store the new list of unpublished ones.

As to how to store them, I'm not a PHP programmer, but what about using PHP's [serialize and unserialize functions](https://www.php.net/serialize)? In python, I'd use the pickle module if I had to store data objects of some type, and I understand those are the PHP equivalent.